# RxJS: how do you know what needs to be cleaned up when using Observable.create

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to get a better understanding of cleaning up after I create a custom Observable.  In order to avoid memory leaks you are suppose to clean up with a disposable function.  In this case I used a Rx method of timer rather than `setInterval` and I believe that when I call `observer.onCompleted()` that internally cleans up the timer and my disposable is useless.  Is my understanding of this process correct?

```
function countInterval(interval, times) {
  return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {  
    var timerId = Rx.Observable.timer(0, interval)
      .subscribe(count => {
        if (count>=times) {
          console.log('')
          observer.onNext(true);
          // I believe this already cleans up internal
          // references to setTimeout but I am not sure
          observer.onCompleted();
        }
      });

    // creating a disposable
    return () => {
      console.log('dispose')
      timerId.dispose();
    }
  });
```

}

feel free to play with this example here:
https://jsbin.com/vojiduzopo/edit?js,console,output
There is also a version where I use `setInterval` with a call to 'clearInterval' as a disposable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it works.

1. You pass a function to `Observable.create`. That function is called whenever the observable that you are creating is subscribed to.
2. Your function receives a `Subscriber` that exposes `next`, `error`, and `complete`. Your job is to call those three functions in the proper order, building up what looks like a sequence of values, from the point of view of the downstream observer.
3. In order to do the proper calls on the `Subscriber` you received, you might acquire resources, such as subscriptions on more basic observables that you're working with. We'll call these upstream observables. (Remember: subscriptions require resources, specifically memory). Subscriptions that you make in the body of your create function are called inner subscriptions.
4. Your create function returns a function that will become your dispose method. It will be called when the observable that you created is disposed, either by its `complete()` method being called, its erroring out, or the subscriber manually calls dispose.

Your understanding of this process is not correct. When you signal completion to your downstream observer, then things downstream of you will clean up, and then your dispose method will be called so that you can clean yourself up. You do have some cleanup, because the inner subscription that you made on a timer will not be cleaned up just because the downstreams are disposed. That timer is still ticking until you dispose it yourself. It doesn't know about anything downstream of it, because you are the one who's connecting it to downstream observers. Your code at the bottom that disposes the timer sub is necessary to avoid a leak.

Comment: I hear what you are saying and I believed it until I created this code.  In my jsbin if you don't dispose of my setInterval version it goes on forever, but in this version the timer ends as soon as you call `observer.onCompleted()`

Comment: https://jsbin.com/pamazifore/edit?js,console,output

I put a .do() on the timer. Go ahead and comment out the disposable that I'm returning in create. The timer won't stop ticking. For that matter something even worse is happening without the disposal, which is that the observable you're creating continues to call onNext() after it calls onCompleted(), which is a huge no-no.

Comment: On one hand I feel very much more enlightened but still a little confused.  Am I right in thinking from the example you gave that RxJS calls the disposable internally after you set it up since you did not call it in your code?

Comment: If I understand your question, the answer is yes. Observable.create arranges for the disposable that you returned to be called when the subscriber is disposed.  Subscriptions are automatically disposed when the onComplete is signalled. So when you tell observer that it's complete, then the RxJS framework disposes you.

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating your own Observable using `Rx.Observable.Create` you are responsible for cleanup of memory (if required). In your example you create a timer, which if not cleaned up would result in a memory leak.

Upon completion of the stream every Observable's `dispose()` function in the stream will be called. Calling `dispose()` manually is signalling that you are no longer interested in results from upstream and will also result in dispose() chaining upstream unless otherwise prevented by things like `share()` .

Comment: Thank you, what I am confused about is after I call `observer.onCompleted()` I have no more logs from `Observable.timer` without having to call `dispose`.  This is not the case when I create a `setInterval`.  On that I have to call `clearInterval` to make it stop.  Are you saying that timer keeps going even though I no longer am getting the `console.logs` from it?